# SQL count with join

Tags: sql, join, count

Total novice.  Trying this again.

2 Tables Biz and Users

Business has IdNum, created_at, account_type, business_name
Users has IdNum, country, first_name, last_name

Question:  How many total businesses are from Japan?

I know I need to use inner join.

Comment: are those the `only` columns? because it would not seem likely that they both join via their id columns. Supply some sample data from each table, remove any info considered private first.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. You say there are only two tables, Users and Biz -- then you join Db_Users and Db_Partners. You are looking for Canada, but use 'JP'.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the total count of all businesses from Canada (assuming you can join from the ID field in Users to the ID field in Biz), counting each distinct business only once-

```
select count(distinct u.country) --will only count unique entries once
from Biz b
inner join Users u 
on b.ID = u.ID
where u.country = 'Japan'
```

If you wanted a count of all rows, instead of the unique rows-

```
select count(u.country) --will count all entries
from Biz b
inner join Users u 
on b.ID = u.ID
where u.country = 'Japan'
```

Comment: the left joins in your examples are overridden by the where clause conditions, should be inner joins, also, use table aliases in all column references.

Comment: @Used_By_Already there is only 1 column reference, and that name doesn't exit in both tables.  code should run either way, but i'll add it for consistency.  also about inner vs left join, they will both do the same thing after the filter is applied because mismatches will be NULL.  even if I did an inner join, I would still have to add the where clause for u.country filter.

Comment: "about inner vs left join, they will both do the same thing" = `exactly my point` so don't use the more expensive left join... there is an element of education involved in answering

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions and created this example.

First I created two tables, db_users and db_partners and
inserted some sample data. I am assuming "Users" are
sales managers for the "Partners" and that each partner
is assigned one user. Users can have multiple partners.
It is strange that "Country" is an attribute of Users and
not Partners, but that was how I interpreted the example.

```
MariaDB [test_time]> create table db_users ( 
  UserID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  UserName varchar(20),
  Country varchar(8) 
);

MariaDB [test_time]> create table db_partners ( 
  PartnerID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  PartnerName varchar(20),
  Created datetime,
  Size int unsigned,
  UserID int unsigned
);

MariaDB [test_time]> insert into db_users
  (UserName,Country) 
values 
  ('Abel','CA'),
  ('Baker','CA'),
  ('Charlie','JP'),
  ('Donald','JP'),
  ('Edgar','JP')
;

MariaDB [test_time]> insert into db_partners 
  (PartnerName,Created,Size,UserID) 
values 
  ('Kraft',now(),45,1),
  ('Ford',now(),66,2),
  ('Hortons',now(),22,1),
  ('Kroger',now(),15,4)
;
```

Then I selected the partners where the associated user was in CA:

```
MariaDB [test_time]> select 
  UserName,PartnerName 
from 
  db_users join db_partners using (UserID) 
where 
  Country='CA'
;
+----------+-------------+
| UserName | PartnerName |
+----------+-------------+
| Abel     | Kraft       |
| Abel     | Hortons     |
| Baker    | Ford        |
+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test_time]> select 
  count(Country) 
from 
  db_users join db_partners using (UserID) 
where 
  Country='CA'
;
+----------------+
| count(Country) |
+----------------+
|              3 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am not sure this is what you wanted. If not, please clarify your
question.

Answer (score 0):

If IdNum is your foreign key (join condition between your tables) just use

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Business, Users
WHERE Business.IdNum = Users.IdNum
AND  Business.country = 'Japan';
```